# MediaRecorder crash

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

---

Very beginner in Android/Java, coming from C and Symbian, I started from the Hellworld example to try to display the sound level (the project is to record this level in a text file for hours).
This code is written in the MainActivity file, as a method inside the MainActivity Class :

```
public void GetAFlevel(View view) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    float audiolevel = 0, maxal = 0;
    MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
    mRecorder.prepare();
    mRecorder.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        audiolevel = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        if (audiolevel > maxal)
            maxal = audiolevel;
    }
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText1.setText(String.valueOf(maxal));
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}
```

The result is a crash of the application on the target :

```
11-17 00:23:09.859: D/AndroidRuntime(22096): Shutting down VM

11-17 00:23:09.859: W/dalvikvm(22096): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)

11-17 00:23:09.921: E/AndroidRuntime(22096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-17 00:23:09.921: E/AndroidRuntime(22096): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

No crash if I remove the following MediaRecorder functions : setAudioSource, setOutputFormat, setAudioEncoder, setOutputFile, prepare, start and stop, but getMaxAmplitude  returns 0, of course.

As soon as I add only setAudioSource (normaly the only necessary for getMaxAmplitude), crash !

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Hi

Finally found a way to have a working code : I put it inside the OnCreate Method :

```
package com.example.mfa;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MediaRecorder mRecorder  =null;
    public float audiolevel=0,maxal=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaRecorder mRecorder  = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mRecorder.start();
        for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        audiolevel=mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude ();
        if (audiolevel>maxal) maxal=audiolevel;}
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText1.setText(String.valueOf(maxal));   
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

remarks : no problem with setOutputFile("/dev/null");
mRecorder.prepare(); surrounded with try/catch

OK but if I put the same code inside an other method called by a button, crash, WHY ??
The same if the button create a new activity : code must be in OnCreate method or crash.

Thanks for help : need to return to basics of JAVA ?